# XSLT not able to resolve file path while using direct-vm in JBoss FSW Switchyard

Tags: xslt, jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse, switchyard

We have developed integration components(Consumer, Router & Provider) using JBoss FSW. The flow of our integration is, a request will come to the consumer, the router will do transformation or routing logic, and the provider will call the actual provider and return the response to the calling program.

In this, we are doing some translation using XSLT. XSLT is referring to XML document, which is available in the classpath. But XSLT is not able to resolve XML document while using **direct-vm://**, but the same is working while using **vm://**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/> -->
    <xsl:param name="metaData" select="document('../xml/MappingReference.xml')" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

URI for Direct-VM:
direct-vm://Translator

Please let me know if you need any other details.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks